# I can't get the sum of the list

Tags: java

I write a code that generates 50 random numbers and then i want to get the sum of all of them:

public class MyClass {

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Generate 50 different prices
    int a = 1;
    while (a < 50) {
        int num = Math.random() * 100 + 1;
        numbers.add(num);
        a = a + 1;
    }
    // System.out.println("test");
    System.out.println(calculateTotal());
}

public static int calculateTotal() {
    int total;
    for (Integer price : numbers) {
        total = price;
    }
    return total;
}
```

}

I have errors in the total of the function and I dont understand why, im only getting the total. How can I fix it ?

Comment: What do you think the line `total = price` does inside that loop? Or rather: What do you expect the line to do? Also: are you sure about the "im only getting the total"?

Comment: why people voted negative and closed my post ? I think is a normal question...

Comment: Because the error is rather easy to spot and also easy to backtrack. If you are printing a sum of 50 random values from 0-100 and the output is something like 17, you are not summing up anything, giving you a further hint.

Comment: the problem was that i cant print anything. anyway is solved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do it in parts

- Generate random numbers. You are generating from `a = 1` to `a = 49` random numbers insted of 50. If you know how many times you want to iterate, you may use the `for` loop.
- `Math.random()` returns a double, so you have to cast to int with `(int)` before it. See documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--)
- In `calculateTotal()` you are iterating over `numbers` but you are not adding to `total`, so the value of `total` would be the last element of `numbers`. Also you have to initialize the variable `total` to 0, otherwise you will get an error.
- I add an extra function to calculate the total with lambda and streams included in Java 8. The `Integer::intValue` calls the method by reference.

```
public class MyClass {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Generate 50 different prices
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            int num = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1); // Add casting
            numbers.add(num);
        }

        System.out.println(calculateTotal());
        System.out.println(calculateTotalJava8());
    }

    public static int calculateTotal() {
        int total = 0; // Initialize to 0
        for (Integer price : numbers) {
            total += price; // Add the price to the total
        }
        return total;
    }
    
    public static int calculateTotalJava8() {
        int total = numbers.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
        return total;
    }
}
```